# SwiftData is not deleting data

Tags: swiftui, swift-data

I'm trying to delete book notes from my `bookNotes` array in `Book` model. When I delete, some are deleted and some are not.

This is my model:

```
//
//  Book.swift
//  Bookworm
//
//  Created by Mehmet Fırat Şirin on 19.11.2023.
//

import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
class Book {
    var title: String
    var desc: String
    var author: String
    var creationDate: Date
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var bookNotes = [BookNote]()
    
    init(title: String, desc: String, author: String, creationDate: Date = .now) {
        self.title = title
        self.desc = desc
        self.author = author
        self.creationDate = creationDate
    }
}

@Model
class BookNote {
    var title: String
    var note: String
    var page: Int
    var creationDate: Date
    var rating: Int
    
    init(title: String, note: String, page: Int, creationDate: Date = .now, rating: Int) {
        self.title = title
        self.note = note
        self.page = page
        self.creationDate = creationDate
        self.rating = rating
    }
}

enum sorting: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    var id : Self {
        return self
    }
    case byTitle = "Başlığa göre"
    case byAuthor = "Yazara göre"
    case byDate = "Tarihe göre"
    
    var systemImage: String {
        switch self {
        case .byTitle:
            "character"
        case .byAuthor:
            "person.fill"
        case .byDate:
            "calendar"
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my code. I'm having problem with `deleteNote` function. I'm inserting sample notes, then I'm deleting all notes. When I launch the app again, some notes are deleted and some are not. Weird problem.

```
//
//  BookDetailView.swift
//  Bookworm
//
//  Created by Mehmet Fırat Şirin on 19.11.2023.
//

import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct BookDetailView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    @Bindable var book : Book
    @State private var sheetBool = Bool()
    @State private var hapticBool = Bool()
    @State private var alertBool = Bool()
    
    let dateFormat = Date.FormatStyle()
        .locale(.current)
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section("Eser Bilgileri") {
                TextField("Başlık (Zorunlu)", text: $book.title)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .textInputAutocapitalization(.words)
                TextField("Yazar (Zorunlu)", text: $book.author)
                    .textInputAutocapitalization(.words)
            }
            Section("Eser Hakkında Notlar") {
                TextField("Not Ekleyin", text: $book.desc, axis: .vertical)
                
            }
            Section("Oluşturulma Tarihi") {
                Text(book.creationDate.formatted(dateFormat))
                    .font(.headline)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                
            }
            if !book.bookNotes.isEmpty {
                Section {
                    ForEach(book.bookNotes) { bookNote in
                        NavigationLink(value: bookNote) {
                            BookNoteListRowView(bookNote: bookNote)
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteNote)
                }
            }
            Section {
                Button("Eserden alıntılar eklemek için tıklayın") {
                    hapticBool.toggle()
                    sheetBool.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(book.title)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationDestination(for: BookNote.self) {
            BookDetailEditView(book: book, bookNote: $0)
        }
        .sensoryFeedback(.impact(weight: .light, intensity: 1), trigger: hapticBool)
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheetBool) {
            AddBookNoteView(book: book)
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                Button(action: {
                    alertBool.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                        .foregroundStyle(.red)
                })
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                Button("Add Samples", systemImage: "plus") {
                    let bookNote1 = BookNote(title: String(), note: "1", page: 1, rating: 1)
                    let bookNote2 = BookNote(title: String(), note: "2", page: 2, rating: 2)
                    let bookNote3 = BookNote(title: String(), note: "3", page: 3, rating: 3)
                    let bookNote4 = BookNote(title: String(), note: "4", page: 4, rating: 4)
                    let bookNote5 = BookNote(title: String(), note: "5", page: 5, rating: 5)
                    book.bookNotes.append(bookNote1)
                    book.bookNotes.append(bookNote2)
                    book.bookNotes.append(bookNote3)
                    book.bookNotes.append(bookNote4)
                    book.bookNotes.append(bookNote5)
                }
            }
        }
        .alert("Emin misiniz?", isPresented: $alertBool) {
            Button("Sil", role: .destructive, action: deleteBook)
            Button("Vazgeç", role: .cancel) { }
        } message: {
            Text("\(book.title) eserini silmek istediğinize emin misiniz?")
        }
    }
    // I'm having problem with this func
    func deleteNote(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        book.bookNotes.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
    
    func deleteBook() {
        modelContext.delete(book)
        dismiss()
    }
}

#Preview {
    do {
        let config = ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true)
        let modelContainer = try ModelContainer(for: Book.self, configurations: config)
        let book = Book(title: "Tutunamayanlar", desc: "Okuması zor bir roman olmasına rağmen herkesin okuması gereken bir romandır.", author: "Oğuz Atay")
        return BookDetailView(book: book)
            .modelContainer(modelContainer)
    } catch {
        return Text("ModelContainer oluşturulurken bir hata oluştu : \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

I tried every deletion method but none of them worked. I kept getting the same problem.

Comment: `book.bookNotes.remove(atOffsets: offsets)`, this will delete the relationship between `book` and the notes given by offsets but it will not delete the actual `BookNote` objects.

Comment: Thank you for your comment so what should I do for solution? Do you have any advice?

Comment: Call `modelContext.delete` for each object instead of removing them